# How do I create a new dataframe using grouped output from another dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have tick data containing symbols, bid prices, and ask prices. I was able to find the average spread and standard deviation of each symbol.

I'd like to create a confidence interval for each symbol and have the final DataFrame output have the columns

- ticker symbol
- average spread
- lower bound 95% confidence
- upper    bound 95% confidence

How can I do that? This is how far I've been able to get:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\William\\Desktop\\tickdata.csv',
                 dtype={'ticker': str, 'bidPrice': np.float64, 'askPrice': np.float64, 'afterHours': str},
                 usecols=['ticker', 'bidPrice', 'askPrice', 'afterHours'],
                 nrows=3000000
                 )

df = df[df.afterHours == "False"]
df = df[df.bidPrice != 0]
df = df[df.askPrice != 0]
df['spread'] = (df.askPrice - df.bidPrice)

print(df.groupby(['ticker'])['spread'].mean())
print(df.groupby(['ticker'])['spread'].std(ddof=0) * 1.96)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call pd.dataframe on it.

`new_df = pd.dataframe(df.groupby(['ticker'])['spread'].mean())`
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: Hey! How can I add a second column to it to contain the standard deviation calculation as well and have it match up by ticker? I think that's what's confusing me and after that it would be straight forward for me to create a 3rd and 4th column containing the intervals

Comment: use pd.merge on the ticker.  how="left',left_on='ticker', etc.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html